# SmtpClient class not picking up default parameters from Web.Config file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

config file :

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp from="YYYYY@xxxxxx.com">
<network
host="mail.xxxxxx.com"
port="25"
password="password"
userName="user@xxxxxx.com"
defaultCredentials="false"
/>
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I've already tried defaultCredentials="true" but i recieved following message:

System.FormatException: Smtp server returned an invalid response.

how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Set the deliveryMethod property on the smtp element to 'network'.

Answer (score 4):

sorry, had the web.config from the Views folder in ASP.NET MVC open, not the one in the application root - DOH!!!!!

Working fine now :))

Comment: I did this too... cost me hours of head scratching.

Answer (score 2):

Where have you placed these elements inside your web.config? They should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="YYYYY@xxxxxx.com">
        <network host="mail.xxxxxx.com" port="25" password="password" userName="user@xxxxxx.com" defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
<configuration>
```

But based on the exception you're getting it sounds like the config is working but your message is improperly formatted. What does your MailMessage look like? What are you passing as your From, Email, Subject and Body?