# web.config contents doesn't affects SmtpClient() configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem trying to configure mail sending via SmtpClient.

I configure it trough web.config file with code like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mail@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mail@gmail.com" password="pass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Then sending a message:

```
mailMessage = new MailMessage("mail@gmail.com", "mail@gmail.com", Subj, message.ToString());
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient()) { 
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); 
}
```

But at this moment I'm receiving an exception saying that SMTP-host isn't specified. 
I tried to initialize it this way: new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"), then I received another exception about SSL required but not configured.

So, obviously, web.config content is just ignored. How do I specify that all necessary setting are actually there?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329411/smtpclient-class-not-picking-up-default-parameters-from-web-config-file

Comment: oh my, haven't even noticed there is two web.configs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web.config's contents don't look like the application-root web.config, but something stored in a subdirectory (e.g. `mywebsite.com/foo/web.config` instead of `mywebsite.com/web.config`)

Move your `<system.net><mailSettings>` configuration elements to the web.config file in the root of your application and then it should work.